# Numeric Keyboard with a diferent layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

after 13.10 update my numeric keyboard isn't working as it's should.

the numbers are fine, but when I press ∕ "slash" it's show a different / "slash" then when I press  + .

The numeric keypad slash is not the "right on" for something like: "ls /home".

When I press ⋅ (it's should be an * instead ⋅).

I realise that if I hold  those keys works fine.

How to solve this? I've tried to change my layout but it didn't help at all...

My Layout is a brazilian keyboard ABNT2 with a numeric keyboard from a Samsung NP550P5C

Thanks in advanced  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your os is probably set to qwerty as the default try changing it in the settings i had the same problem but i had a qwerty keyboard while it was set to a japanese keyboard so all the keys were Everywhere so qwerty would be asrfguo

Answer (score 0):

You can change it Like this:

---

Sorry. Your browser does not support the video tag. Please go [here](http://ubuntuone.com/34VcpS0iWkvodJCiaaSOZP) to watch the video.

[watch the video](http://ubuntuone.com/34VcpS0iWkvodJCiaaSOZP)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your video.
I did it, actually, but is didn't work, I've tried all brazilian layouts, it's change my layout for my keyboard but doesn't affect my numeric keyboard :s
But thanks anyway

Comment: :( then wait for someone else to solve the problem... Hope you'll find it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the numeric keypad layout with [gnome-tweak-tool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-tweak-tool). Under **Typing** you'll see **Numeric keypad layout selection**. It sounds like you have currently one that has "Unicode additions." Try the different options.

Answer (score 0):

The numeric keypad layout must be configured with gnome-tweak-tool. Go to keyboard & mouse/additional options/ and in numeric keyboard layout, choose to disable.